# IE doesn't seem to cache my images

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I really hope someone has some ideas. I have set up my web config to cache images for 30 days.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Yet when I request the page with IE and checkout network traffic this is what I see:

```
Request Header:

Key Value
Request GET http://www.xx.com/Content/Icons/login.png HTTP/1.1
Accept  image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5
Referer http://www.selftestware.com/
Accept-Language en-US
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    www.xx.com
If-Modified-Since   Wed, 24 Aug 2011 15:48:10 GMT
If-None-Match   W/"0195d397562cc1:0"
Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive
Pragma  no-cache
Cookie  __utma=xx

Response:

Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   public,max-age=2592000
Content-Type    image/png
Last-Modified   Wed, 24 Aug 2011 15:48:10 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
ETag    W/"0195d397562cc1:0"
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Wed, 24 Aug 2011 10:39:14 GMT
Content-Length  727
```

Should it not send a 304 (not modified). I just can't understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Why can I see "Pragma  no-cache" in the request header??

Comment: It's not anything that is set by me. My application is an out of the box implementation of MVC3 running on WIndows Azure.

Comment: I think you have to find a way to remove it..!

Comment: the "pragma: no-cache" is a red herring in this case - I see this in the request header and still get a 304 response as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your request header was sent a "**Pragma: no-cache**" which means told the server not to cache this request.  That's why your server response HTTP 200 rather than HTTP 304.

This "**Pragma: no-cache**" was sent by the browser.  If you press Ctrl+F5 hotkey or configured your browser not to cache anything will cause this result.  You can try to create a blank page that contains a link to this cached page, then click the link on it.  You'll see this page been cached.